# Using Struct in ActionMailer preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I am testing one of my mailers using ActionMailer Preview and am using `Struct` to create my objects

```
class TransactionMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  include Roadie::Rails::Automatic

  def transaction_complete_mailer
    orders = Struct.new(:image, :image_size, :mount, :frame, :frame_color)
    transaction = Struct.new(:first_name, :email)
    @transaction = transaction.new('Richard Lewis', 'test@gmail.com')
    @orders = orders.new("Test Print Name", "10x8 Image Size", "10x8 Mount Size", "10x8 Frame Size", "White Frame")
    TransactionMailer.transaction_complete_mailer(@transaction, @orders) 
  end
end
```

This is my actual mailer class

```
class TransactionMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: ENV['EMAIL_ADDRESS']

  def transaction_complete_mailer(transaction, orders)
    @transaction = transaction
    @orders = orders
    attachments.inline['photography-logo-text.png'] = File.read(Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', 'photography-logo-text.png'))
    mail(to: @transaction.email, subject: 'Your order from Glenn GB Photography') do |format|
      format.html { render file: 'transaction_mailer/transaction_message.html.erb', layout: 'mailer' }
    end
  end
end
```

In my view I loop over the `@orders` as there could be multiple

transaction_message.htmnl.erb

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
  <div class="order-summary">
    <p><span class="bold">Print:</span><%= order.image %></p>
    <p><span class="bold">Print Size:</span><%= order.image_size %></p>
    <p><span class="bold">Mount:</span><%= order.mount %></p>
    <p><span class="bold">Frame:</span><%= order.frame %></p>
    <p><span class="bold">Frame Color:</span><%= order.frame_color %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I action this mailer in preview I get an error

```
undefined method `image' for "Test Print Name":String
```

I have two questions here

1. Why am I getting the error?
2. How would I create multiple order objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@orders` is a singular object of type `struct`, but your your `transaction_complete_mailer` expects an array/collection named `@orders`. So when you call `@orders.each do |order|` in your Mailer, it's actually iterating through each key/value in the `@orders` struct object. This explains the error you're getting since `"Test Print Name"` is the first key declared in your `Struct`.

Wrapping your structs in an array should resolve the issue:

```
class TransactionMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  include Roadie::Rails::Automatic

  def transaction_complete_mailer
    orders = Struct.new(:image, :image_size, :mount, :frame, :frame_color)
    transaction = Struct.new(:first_name, :email)
    @transaction = transaction.new('Richard Lewis', 'test@gmail.com')
    @order = orders.new("Test Print Name", "10x8 Image Size", "10x8 Mount Size", "10x8 Frame Size", "White Frame") # Renamed to @order, since this is a single object
    TransactionMailer.transaction_complete_mailer([@transaction], [@order]) 
  end
end
```

Comment: ah thank you, now that makes a lot of sense :-) do you know how i would create multiple records using struct ?

Comment: A struct basically a Hash object that acts like a traditional Ruby object, it's intended to represent a singular object not a collection. You could have a field of the struct be an array, but that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: ook, thanks, will use alternative approach, thanks though, cleared something up for me at least

Comment: No problem, best of luck.